# JavaScript: automatic getters and setters in closures without eval?

Tags: javascript, closures

**Note**: there are a lot of questions regarding getters and setters in JavaScript (see [Javascript Getters And Setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134597/javascript-getters-and-setters), [Getters and Setters in a function (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367348/getters-and-setters-in-a-function-javascript), [Getters and Setters in JavaScript (Correct syntax ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123017/getters-and-setters-in-javascript-correct-syntax), [automatic getter and setter(with validation) in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461062/automatic-getter-and-setterwith-validation-in-javascript), etc). Most of these questions deal with `Objects`, a few with `Closures` and rather few of them with automatically producing getters and sets. This question deals with the later.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17461210/5623899) to [automatic getter and setter(with validation) in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461062/automatic-getter-and-setterwith-validation-in-javascript) is perhaps the closest for what I am looking for, but not-ideal for my use case.

Currently, in my closure I have the following:

```
function myClosure() {
  var closureVar1, closureVar2

  function do () { ... }

  function setupSettersAndGetters() {

    var closureVariables = ['closureVar1', 'closureVar2']

    for (var i = 0; i < closuredVariables.length; i++) {

      var currentClosureVariable = closureVariable[i]
      var toEvaluateString = "                                                 \
      do." + currentClosureVariable + " = function(value){                     \
        if(!arguments.length) return " + currentClosureVariable + ";           \
        " + currentClosureVariable + " = value;                                \
        return setup;                                                          \
      };                                                                       \
      "
      eval(toEvaluateString)
    }
  }
  setupSettersAndGetters()
  return do;
}
```

This works exactly as I like, e.g.

```
var test = myClosure()
test.closureVar1(10).closureVar2(2)
test.closureVar1() + test.closureVar2() // return 12
```

There is just the one "tiny" problem of using `eval` which some people [detest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

So my question is, is there a better way to handle this and allow for me to call the setter / getter by name, rather than using a string?

e.g. I could use an intermediate function such as:

```
test.sget('closureVar1', 10) // set closureVar1 to 10
test.sget('closureVar2') // get closureVar2
```

but even doing that I think I still need to use `eval`? and I would prefer calling the name of the variable...

Thoughts?

Comment: Look into [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: @Xufox will do, looks useful, but understanding the js docs has always been a challenge to me... I learned JS basically via w3schools (which gives almost no technical details of JS) and by fiddling around with d3. So if you also know a place to get a good rundown of how to do JS properly, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Well, that very same documentation page, MDN, is where I would point you to.

Comment: @Xufox alright Ill spend more time with the MDN docs :)

Comment: @SumNeuron I'm not understanding your question... if you're familiar with D3, why don't you use the classic pattern? Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/jq5t5L2t/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you can see that pattern in the evaluation string (taken from d3 source). The issue is when I have a lot of variables. Python has the property decorator to automatically generate getter and setters. If I have 20 vars, is copy-paste the same function 20 times the only answer without eval? I'll do it, but seems sub-par :P

Comment: If you have 20 vars, why don't you create a function to generate the getter/setter function automatically?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that is the question :) but mine (see `toEvaluateString` in post) uses evals and I do not know how to do it without eval

Comment: @SumNeuron Well, there are plenty of alternatives without eval, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xy0xwjkn/1/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that looks really nice, but how can I handle default values? also, then users (and or myself) have to know and always call the entire list of variables that need scope under the closure...

Comment: @SumNeuron you're making additional questions. I'd advise to make small steps here at S.O., otherwise it will be hard for you to get a proper answer. If you want me to write an answer, just let me know.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado fair point, technically this question is just "without eval" and your answer does solve it. Go ahead post it here, ill +1 it. Ill give a day for others to post suggestions prior to marking an answer. Ill add a second question for no eval with default values

Comment: @SumNeuron No worries. That's exactly my point: other users can improve upon already existing answers, adding features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the arguments passed to your `myClosure` function...

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

... and use them to set up your setters and getters:

```
args.forEach(function(arg) {
    instance[arg] = function(d) {
        if (!arguments.length) return arg;
        arg = d;
        return instance;
    };
});
```

That way, you can pass how many variables you want and also avoiding `eval`.

Here is a demo:

```js
function myClosure() {
  var instance = {};
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.forEach(function(arg) {
    instance[arg] = function(d) {
      if (!arguments.length) return arg;
      arg = d;
      return instance;
    };
  })
  return instance;
};

var test = myClosure("v1", "v2", "v3")
test.v1(16).v2(2).v3(8)
console.log(test.v1() + test.v2() + test.v3())
```

Comment: follow up question is also around if you want to take a crack at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474370/javascript-default-arguments-in-automatic-getters-and-setters-in-closures-witho